# Cannot fully shutdown Windows partition

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

I can not mount my Windows partition while using my Ubuntu 15.10 OS. The system claims that Windows is hibernating and prompts me to mount the partition in read-only mode *( mount "nfts" -ro)*.

That works for me to access my files. However, it would be much better to be able to read and write to that partition. I have already turned off all suspension options in my energy plan (normal suspension and hybrid suspension both) but that don't seem to do the trick.

I've also deinstalled Samsung Fast Start-Up and tried to run

```
powercfg -h off
```

on the command prompt. It says it cannot complete the action.

Comment: I've just seen there a lot of similar questions like this one. Feel free to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Simply turning off the ability to hibernate in Windows should also delete c:\hiberfil.sys, allowing Ubuntu to mount the partition. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/920730